# How to pass string parameters dynamically in innerHTML onclick event

Tags: javascript

I am trying to parse a date parameter in a function name select_day. That function is declared in for a li element onclick event. with the below code I am getting this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

it's actually a date that I am trying to pass. I have tried hard coding the parameter, its working but dynamically it's not working

```
if(selected_day == dates[i]){
             $(".dates_list").append( "<li class='active' onclick=\'select_day("+$.datepicker.formatDate( "dd M", dates[i])+")\'><span>Day "+day_count+"</span><p>"+$.datepicker.formatDate( "dd M", dates[i]) +"</p></li>" );
        }
```

I want that function to be executed. Could anyone help please

Comment: Count your open `(` and your closing `)`. One is missing. Probably at the very end(?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `.on('click'` handler instead of trying to concatenate the Javascript code to be executed into an `onclick` inline handler:

```
if(selected_day == dates[i]){
  const $li = $(`<li class="active"><span>Day ${day_count}</span><p>${$.datepicker.formatDate( "dd M", dates[i])}</p></li>`);
  $li.on('click', () => {
    select_day($.datepicker.formatDate("dd M", dates[i]));
  });
  $(".dates_list").append($li);
}
```

Or, more concisely:

```
if(selected_day == dates[i]){
  const formattedDate = $.datepicker.formatDate( "dd M", dates[i]);
  $(`<li class="active"><span>Day ${day_count}</span><p>${formattedDate}</p></li>`)
    .on('click', () => {
      select_day(formattedDate, dates[i]);
    })
    .appendTo('.dates_list');
}
```

Handlers attached with Javascript are generally a lot easier to manage than `on-` attribute strings.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the missing of opening and closing quotes.

I recommend you [event-delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for doing this as well as to embrace the binding of events rather than putting events directly into the markup.

Likewise, you can use the [`data`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) attribute to store the dates.  Further, I added the class `date-list` in order to identify those elements `li`.

```
if (selected_day === dates[i]) {
    let html = "<li data-date='" + $.datepicker.formatDate("dd M", dates[i]) + "' class='date-list active'><span>Day " + day_count + "</span><p>" + $.datepicker.formatDate("dd M", dates[i]) + "</p></li>";
    $(".dates_list").append(html);
}

// Place this in somewhere different than the previous code-snippet 
// and execute it after the DOM is totally loaded
$('.dates_list').on("click", ".date-list", function() {
    select_day(this.data("date"));
});
```

Comment: this .date-list .on(click) is not triggering.

Comment: @Swamsreggae typo `$('.dates_list').on...`